# How to send value to controller from DataList using form with jQuery serialize() method?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have used **DataList** tag in my application, for better searching purpose in drop downs, but I want to send the hidden code that is associated with particular value to my controller and instead its value.

I'm using jQuery form `serialize()` method for sending whole form data. But I'm not getting proper way, what I need to do?

I tried following -

```
<input type="text" name="pubData" class="form-control" id="defaultpublisher" list="department" placeholder="">
<datalist id="department"> </datalist>
```

for this, I'm appending values using jquery like this -

```
$.each(data.department,function(key,val) {
    tag += '<option data-value="'+val.Fld_Dept_Code+'">'+val.Fld_Dept+'</option>';
});
$("#department").append(tag);
```

please suggest me to set `Fld_Dept_Code` to the database on form submission

Comment: show what you tried - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: <input type="text" name="pubData" class="form-control" id="defaultpublisher" list="department" placeholder="">
<datalist  id="department">
      
</datalist> for this I'm appending values using j query like $.each(data.department,function(key,val){
 tag += '<option  data-value="'+val.Fld_Dept_Code+'">'+val.Fld_Dept+'</option>';
   });
$("#department").append(tag); please suggest me to set Fld_Dept_Code to database on form submission

Comment: more about `serialize()` -  https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_serialize.asp